# How to install Wordpress updates on Google Container Engine?

Tags: php, wordpress, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently setup a Wordpress site hosted on Container Engine, following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress). Now I'm connected to wordpress wp-admin page and trying to update the latest Wordpress version updates. So I click on Dashboard->Updates->Update Now which results in this error:

```
Unpacking the update…

The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation Failed
```

I'm new to kubernetes, and can't seem to find how I can connect to the running wordpress container via the gcloud console, and look at wordpress files and see if there are any permission issues to fix there. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the permissions issues, but you can debug using `kubectl exec`.

If you have a pod named `wordpress-abcde`, you should be able to run `kubectl exec wordpress-abcde -i -t sh` to open up a shell in in the (only) container in that pod. Here's the docs for [kubectl exec](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/kubectl/exec).